# Can someone provide step-by-step explanation of the setState code from official React documentation challenge?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#challenges

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function RequestTracker() {
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(0);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(0);

  async function handleClick() {
    setPending(pending + 1);
    await delay(3000);
    setPending(pending - 1);
    setCompleted(completed + 1);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h3>
        Pending: {pending}
      </h3>
      <h3>
        Completed: {completed}
      </h3>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        Buy     
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

after i click on "Buy" three times, value of pending changes from 0 to -1 and later to 1. and value of completed from 0 to 1. useEffect and console log in it show that value of pending changes like -1,0,1 and i would like to get step-by-step explanation why is this happening.